# Microsoft Edge version 40/15 clipboard returns strange string for 'text/html'

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I just find that in Microsoft Edge v40/15 , when you paste some text from a `<div contenteditable=true>`, into the same `<div>` and get the data with `e.clipboard.getData("text/html")`, what I get is some thing confusing, instead of the part I pasted, I got a bunch of something like debugging information, like in the picture below (inside `<div id="display">`), what I actually pasted is only `<p>paragraph element</p>`:

[image]

I made a jsfiddle for it, you could try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/larryzhao/wfy60y07/ . Paste something from the contenteditable div into the same one with Microsoft Edge v40/15 and the thing will be shown in the div below.

I'd like to know if Microsoft Edge v40/15 is publicly released? Is it a bug or a feature from Microsoft Edge? I can't find it anywhere on the web.

Comment: Not reproducible on my version.38.14

Comment: @RobParsons there's nothing wrong with v38.14, but if you upgrade to v40...

Comment: Im using the current public version, just letting you know. I think you can confidently raise a bug report for it at the Edge feedback portal... https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/ other ppl on the same build as you will be able to confirm it for you... I should have just told you the link...

Comment: "I'd like to know if IE Edge v40/15 is publicly released?" No because there is no such thing as "IE Edge" (except the built-in mode in IE itself). "Is it a bug or a feature from IE?" No because this isn't even IE. This is Microsoft Edge. **They are not the same thing.** That might be why you can't find anything on the web.

Comment: He can't find anything on the web, 'cause there seems nothing on the web at the moment. But - yes Edge 40/15 is not yet publicly available, it comes with Microsofts Win10 preview VMs though.

Answer (score 0):

In Edge 40/15 Microsoft has added `text/html` portion to the clipboard, in previous versions (even in the one that is publicly available at the moment) it wasn't even available.

That part which you consider to be a debugging information, is something that Microsoft has been adding to the clipboard for years (I'm not aware of any details though). So one can be pretty sure that it's there to stay. I guess the only way to address it would be to accommodate your code to the fact that it's there.

There's also another problem with `text/html` content in the Edge 40/15: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11877517/.

> The word document contains unicode characters that are corrupted when pasting into Edge. The pasted content appears fine in ContentEditable, but the data we receive in JavaScript has been translated into what looks like ASCII.
>
> Looking at the second paragraph in the HTML clipboard contents, we expect (and confirmed in Chrome/Firefox):
>
> **śƿęċīǟƪ characters**
>
> Instead Edge gives us:
>
> **Å›Æ¿Ä™Ä‹Ä«ÇŸÆª characters**